# Preventing Time Zone Influence

Tags: gatsby

In a post frontmatter I use this format of date:

```
---
date: 2020-10-23T01:11:32+03:00
---
```

In a query I use this format:

```
frontmatter {
    date(formatString: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss")
}
```

I expect `23.10.2020 01:11:32`, but getting `22.10.2020 22:11:32`.

How can I get `23.10.2020 01:11:32`?

**Addition 1**

This markup:

```
<time className="post-date"><small>{post.frontmatter.date}</small></time>
```

This query:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        lang
        author
        description
        keywords
        title
        siteUrl
      }
    }
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      nodes {
        excerpt
        fields {
          slug
        }
        frontmatter {
          title
          date(formatString: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss")
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple approaches to bypass it.

The most native, trying to use `locale` in your `formatString` filter:

```
frontmatter {
    date(formatString: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss", locale:"en") // en by default, change it to what you need
}
```

`formatString` uses the options provided by `momentjs`, check for more locales and filters in [their documentation](https://momentjs.com/).

If the previous approach doesn't fit your specifications, you can always play with the result in your JavaScript files, like:

```
const date= props.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes[0].frontmatter.date;
date.format('llll'); // will outpout something like Tue, Oct 27, 2020 7:27 AM
```

*Disclaimer: note that the path to reach the date is faked and dummy, get the workaround, no the path.*

Comment: `locale` doesn't solve the problem.
Other methods are difficult for me, I can't implement them on my own. The date of the article, this is the most important thing in the logic of generation and I did not expect that Gatsby did not solve this issue.
How you write the date and time in the article and how you output it, please show your code.

Comment: How are you retrieving you post data? Show your template/component in order to adapt the answer.

Comment: Your  date is under: `props.data.allMarkdownRemark.nodes[0].frontmatter.date` (note that nodes is an iterable element)

Comment: In the same page that your query is